# After upgrading angular from 8 to 9 error is throwing "Cannot assign value "undefined" to template variable "limit"

Tags: angular, typescript

I just updated my existing Angular 8 project to the latest version of Angular 9. I defined one variable in the different div elements of a template. It is working as expected and did not throw any errors. I don't want to initialize this variable in the .ts file. If I do so then it will be initialized as a global variable and it is affecting all div elements in which I used this variable.

but after upgrading to Angular 9 it is throwing errors of ***'Cannot assign value "undefined" to template variable "limit". template variables are read-only'***.
Can anyone help me to get out of this problem? 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks :)

```
                <p *ngIf="displayLimit; let limit">
                <li *ngFor="let industry of company_industries; let i = index">
                  <simple-tag type="white" class="industry-tag" *ngIf="i < limit" title="{{industry}}">
                  </simple-tag>
                </li>
                <button *ngIf="lessFlag && limit > displayLimit " class="edu_img"
                  (click)="limit = limit - displayLimit " >
                <button *ngIf="limit < info.company_industries?.length" class="edu_img"
                  (click)="limit = limit + displayLimit " (click)="lessFlag = true">
                </p>
```

I have similar sections related to the above code which are using the "limit" variable.

Comment: You are assigning a value to `limit` which is not allowed because it is a readonly variable. Exactly what the error tells you. This was no error before because the template type checks have been improved. This should not have worked to begin with, but there just was no check in place beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 9 have come up with new template checks, that means while developing you will be making less mistakes like you have done above by setting value to a readonly variable.

You can stop these checks by changing properties in tsconfig.json under angularcompileroptions.

For referring to different available checks here is the link of official doc.

https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck

Comment: Hey Aakash, as I have migrated to angular 9 for better tooling so avoiding the type-checks, is not a good solution. by the way Thanks for your support. I read the angular docs after your suggestion.